# Managing new columns by trigger functions for replication from one schema to another in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I wrote few trigger functions to store and make backup of each row on their corresponding table name. The designs seems to work well if the number of columns are fixed. The only issue is that what if later i want to add a new column to the table. I need to add that column in all those replicated schemas.tables also I use $1.* to insert , update rows because the number of columns are more than 30 for each table. I also have columns that store preprocess information of each column such as time, ip address, user token etc. As default if I add a column later on after creating the table, the column will be added at the end so the use of "$1.*" becomes difficult to work with as it will add value to the wrong column or can just give an sql error

> column "test_id" is of type bigint but expression is of type boolean
>
> > LINE 1: insert into users_test.user_info SELECT $1.*

Here is the scenario, I explain it with an example.

We create a table

```
 CREATE TABLE users.user_info
(
    _id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users._ids'::regclass),
    _ts timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    myKey bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users.myKey'::regclass),
    email character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    tel character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    
    user_ip character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    user_token character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    local_agent_login_ts timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT user_info_vkey PRIMARY KEY (myKey)
    )
```

I write a trigger function that will make backup of each new row into another schema and also store preprocess information.

**Trigger Function for backup**

```
CREATE FUNCTION users.update_to_insert()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$declare
   _rec record;
   _rec_new_row record;
   _ref_1 character varying;
   tb_sch_name character varying;
   tb_sch_name_backup character varying;
begin   
    _rec := old;
    _rec_new_row := new;
    _rec._ts = now();
    tb_sch_name = CONCAT(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA,'_history.',TG_TABLE_NAME);
    tb_sch_name_backup = CONCAT(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA,'_backup.',TG_TABLE_NAME);
    _rec.myKey = -1 * nextval('users.myKey');
    _ref_1 = _rec.tel;
    _ref_1 = CONCAT('''',_ref_1,'''');
    --tb_sch_name = regexp_replace(tb_sch_name, '"', '');
    execute format('insert into %s SELECT $1.*',tb_sch_name) using _rec;
    _rec_new_row.myKey = 1 * nextval('users._versions');
    _rec_new_row._ts = now();
    execute format ('update %s set backup_myKey = -1*backup_myKey where tel = %s',tb_sch_name_backup,_ref_1);
    execute format('insert into %s SELECT $1.*',tb_sch_name_backup) using _rec_new_row;
    
return null;

end$BODY$;
```

Trigger function to store Preprocess row information

```
CREATE FUNCTION users.preprocess_logstuff()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$begin

new.local_agent_label = current_role;

new.user_ip = inet_client_addr();

new.user_token = txid_current();

new._ts = now();

new.local_agent_login_ts = now();

return new;
end$BODY$;
```

Now in the other schemas the table structure is similar but they store their own preprocess logs as well. So the structure of the table looks like this

CREATE TABLE users.user_info
(
_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT,
_ts timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
myKey bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT,
email character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
tel character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,

```
    user_ip character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    user_token character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    local_agent_login_ts timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,

    
    backup_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('backup_users._ids'::regclass),
    backup_ts timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    backup_myKey bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('backup_users.myKey'::regclass),
    backup_user_ip character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    backup_user_token character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    backup_local_agent_login_ts timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,  

   CONSTRAINT user_info_vkey PRIMARY KEY (backup_myKey)
    )
```

Same rules for the trigger functions. Now in this scenario if i add a new column in the table, I will have to add those columns in all the other corresponding schemas and tables which I can understand but I cannot find a possible solution in which i don't need to hardcore the columns name and don't face the problem of column positioning when insert , update new row. Because each row interacts with other schemas as well. This makes it complicated to handle. Is there any possible way that i can resolve this issue or neglect some columns. I already tried with EXCEPT but it didn't work, Since I am not sure how exactly EXCEPT can be helpful but any suggestion from the community will be highly regarded.

Comment: Take a look at a solution I came up with some years back [archive solution](http://aklaver.org/wordpress/2012/06/23/postgres-and-hstore/). This used HSTORE, now a day I would probably use JSON.  It is not an exact match to what you want, but it might provide  some pointers.

Comment: It seems that you want to keep the backup tables in sync with changes made to the original tables. That could be done with event triggers.

Comment: I think event triggers can be helpful while altering table, but the problem is with insert and updating rows with the current trigger function i have as in the code it's clearly seen that i am not hardcoding each column name so the position of new columns should be either adjusted in the otherSchema.tableName or the trigger function should exempt those specific columns and put the value in the next positioned column by default. it's like Ball in hole game, we want to jump the ball by 3 holes and aim it at the 4th hole.